# So they say; though, some disagree.

Tags: phrases

A: You are such a great singer!

B: **So they say; though, some disagree.**

Is it OK to use the phrase in bold in these types of situations?

Comment: Sure, it's fine (though a bit theatrical). What worries you about it?

Comment: Using 'they' as a synonym for 'the majority of people with an opinion on the matter',  'the majority of people in power', 'the clever people who are working on this medical problem',  'the companies involved in making this product' etc is standard. However, combining this usage with another group becomes at worst ludicrous. A joke addressing the Irish problem about 25 years ago: 'They say it's not as bad as they say it is.'

Comment: @Dan Bron I just wanted to make sure that the sentence in bold was idiomatic and that I could use it when someone compliment me on something. I think it sounds cool and modest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> So they say; though, some disagree.

The wording is correct but I don't see the function of the comma. Is it intended to indicate a pause? I don't think a pause is necessary. Also I would say that the semicolon is overkill.

My suggestions:

*So they say, though some disagree.*

or

*So they say—though some disagree.*

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I was just trying to use proper punctuation, but I'm still learning about it.